# How to prevent object to be serialize in XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

IDE: VS, C# .net 4.0, winforms

With the help of XMLSerializer I am able to generate XML of C# object, but I want to remove specific objects.

Is there any way to prevent  specific objects to prevent in XML..?

```
 using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            /* 
            XmlSerializer.Serialize Method (XmlWriter, Object)
            Serializes the specified Object and writes the XML document to a file using the specified xmlwriter 

            Parameters
            xmlWriter-

            Type: System.Xml.XmlWriter

            The XmlWriter used to write the XML document. 
            Type: System.Object
            The Object to serialize. 

             */

            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, YourClassObject);
            xmlStream.Position = 0;

            //Loads the XML document from the specified string.
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);

            string fileName = YourClassObject.GetType().Name;
            xmlDoc.Save("C:\\Users\\Yogesh\\Desktop\\Yardz_XMLS\\" + fileName + ".xml");
            return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
```

Is there any way to prevent some properties to be serialize..?

Comment: Prevent serializing specific *objects* or *properties*? The latter is easy. The former, on other hand, depends on what you really mean.

Answer (score 0):

Put [`XmlIgnore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) attribute on properties that you don't what to be serialized:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string Serailized { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string NotSerialized { get; set; }
}
```

See "[Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx)" for more information.